# Dropdownlist inside Updatepanel not working Properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

i put 2 Dropdownlist inside a updatepanel. whenever 1st dropdownlist selected index changes 2nd dropdownlist's item changes.(like Country-State.. here in my case its city-area).

Whenever i change 1st dropdownlist(DDLCity1) selectedindex no problem, it works fine. But Two times only. 
suppose, after page load i select "LA"  no problem, area of LA will load in another dropdownlist DDLArea1. then i nake change, select "NY" city, again another dropdownlist will works fine.

BUT NOW ON THERD ATTEMPT MY 2ND DROPDOWNLIST SHOW NO CHANGES!!!!! IT sTILL SHOW LAST RESULT.

IN SORT, postback works only 2 times.

for testing i put a alert msg on indexchange of dropdown it popups only 2 times. seems like postback only 2 times :(( plzz help me;

```
<pre>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" UpdateMode="Always">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCity1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="- All City -" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLArea1" runat="server" Style="margin-bottom: 0px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLArea_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        AutoPostBack="false" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="- Anywhere -" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <span style="position: absolute;">
                                        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
                                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                                <img src="img/loading.gif" alt="Alternate Text" />
                                            </ProgressTemplate>
                                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                    </span>


                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLCity1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLArea1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
<code>
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
        DDLCity1.DataSource = objsql.GetTable("select distinct city from tblCity where status=1 order by city");
        DDLCity1.DataTextField = "city";
        DDLCity1.DataValueField = "city";
        DDLCity1.DataBind();
        DDLCity1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- All India -", "- All India -"));
        if (Request.Cookies["ddCityCookie"] != null)
        {
            ddlCity.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["ddCityCookie"].Value);

            if (Request.Cookies["ddAreaCookie"] != null)
            {
                ddlArea.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["ddAreaCookie"].Value);
            }
        }
}
protected void DDLCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    DropDownCityIndexChange();

    DDLArea1.SelectedIndex = 0;

}
protected void DDLArea_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie ddAreaCookie = new HttpCookie("ddAreaCookie");
    ddAreaCookie.Value = DDLArea1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    ddAreaCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(ddAreaCookie);
}
public void DropDownCityIndexChange()
{
    DDLArea1.Items.Clear();

    DDLArea1.DataSource = null;

    HttpCookie ddCityCookie = new HttpCookie("ddCityCookie");
    ddCityCookie.Value = DDLCity1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    ddCityCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(ddCityCookie);


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    if (DDLCity1.SelectedItem.Text != "- All India -")
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = objsql.GetTable("select area from tblCity where city='" + DDLCity1.SelectedItem.Text + "' and status=1 order by area");
        if (dt.Rows[0]["area"].ToString() != null && dt.Rows[0]["area"].ToString() != "")
        {
            DDLArea1.DataSource = dt;
            DDLArea1.DataTextField = "area";
            DDLArea1.DataValueField = "area";
            DDLArea1.DataBind();
        }


    }

    DDLArea1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("- Anywhere -", "- Anywhere -"));

}
</code>
```

Comment: HERE IN BOTH DROPDOWN AUTOPOSTBACK IS "True".. WAS MY TYPING MISTAKE..

Comment: Try UpdatePanel1.update(); after dropdown bind

Comment: I tried it. still same problem.   @RAJESH KUMAR

Comment: First try without update panel whether its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove ClientIDMode="Static" Propery